# Difference between 'Database Restore' & 'Database Deployment'?

Tags: sql-server, database

Well, I am new to SQL Server and databases in general. What does it really mean:

1. Restore Database from Snapshot
2. Restore full Database
3. Deploy Database on Virtual machine Server.

Can restoration done after deployment. please could you explain in context of SQL Server?

Answer (score 0):

@techy, in order for you to fully understand the answers to those questions, you will need to do some learning on your own.  There is too much to "teach" in a stackoverflow response.  So below I'll give you some quick answers, and links to where you can learn more.

1. A snapshot is a "point-in-time" copy of a database.  For example, assume I have a database named D1.  I want to be able to keep a copy of D1 as it was at 12:15pm.  So at 12:15 pm I create a snapshot D1 and name it D1Snap1215 (name is unimportant).  I can now query the LIVE data by querying from D1, or the 12:15pm version of the database by querying DSnap1215.  If I choose, I could even revert the live D1 database back to it's 12:15pm state by restoring the database D1 from the DSnap1215 snapshot.  Read about [Database Snapshots](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175158.aspx) and how to [Revert a Database to a Database Snapshot](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189281.aspx).
2. SQL Server allows you to backup your databases at any time. There are various kinds of backups (Full, Differential, Transaction Log, ...).  However a full backup copies the state of the entire database to some backup media (a backup file on a harddrive, or a backup tape, ...).  At a later time, you can restore the database from the backup.  The restore can be done on the original server (or instance), to the same database or event to a different database or instance.  Read more about the [BACKUP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186865%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) and [RESTORE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186858.aspx) statements.
3. Deploying a database is the general process of getting a database onto a SQL Server instance somewhere. The process (from the SQL perspective) is the same whether the target server is physical or virtual.  You can deploy a database to a server by [running scripts to create the database and its structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh245282.aspx), and then [importing the data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140052), or perhaps using a [backup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186865%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) of a database from another server that you [restore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186858.aspx) onto the target server.  There are nuumerous tools from both Microsoft and 3rd parties to help you deploy databases.  For example, the "[Transfer Database Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141204.aspx)" component in SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS) can help you copy or move a database.

Hope that gets you started.